Как из числа DEC сделать HEX по байтам в массив
Дан массивы
byte skoll[]  = {0x40, 0x42, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; // хранит количество DEC = 1 000 000, то есть одна штука

byte sPrice[] = {0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};// хранит цену DEC =516 ( то есть 5.16 рублей)

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы skoll*sPrice=summ, а summ это новый массив также разбит по байтам
UPD:
Смог в DEC то и то перевести, остался вопрос как вернуть как было в новый массив
word x = 0;
        word y = 0;
        word s=0;
        for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
          x = x*256+skoll[i];
        }
        x=x/1000000; // количество
        Serial.println(x);

        for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
          y = y*256+sPrice[i];
        }


Что такое word? Оно вмещает шестибайтовое значение? Dec и hex нужны только человеку как строковое представление, компьютер знает только байты

в word храню значение. Хорошо, если компьютеру нужны ток байты, тогда как мне сделать то же что я сделал без преобразование в DEC, а на уровне байтов

Вы и работаете с байтами, никакого преобразования при этом не происходит. Только при печати по умолчанию выводится десятичный вид. Нужно знать форматы представления данных, у вас они нестандартные  6 и 5 байтов на число, а  про результат пока ничего не говорили. А насчёт word всё-таки есть сомнения.

Хорошо, понял что вы имеете ввиду. Тогда мне не нужно переводить их в DEC,  а работать с ними на в байтах. Но как тогда нужно это сделать? Взять один массив и умножить с другим , а потом так же по байтово раскидать

Нужно описать формат данных.

byte summ[N];
word s = x * y;

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    summ[i] = s % 256;
    s /= 256;
}

Помогло!
Всем Спасибо) Если есть другой вариант, можете предлагать)
